# Backup our sharepoint in-premises farms, are we following correct/sufficient appraoch

Tags: 2013, 2016, administration, sharepoint-on-prem, backup

We have sharepoint on-premises servers 2013/2016 , which have the following architecture:-

1. windows server 2012/2008 R2 which act as the application servers.
2. windows server 2012/2008 R2 which act as the database servers.

Now our IT admins, take snapshots of the servers (application + database) on daily basis + to have additional restore point (in case we faced a sever damage to our servers) i run this command on daily basis to have a backup for the whole farm :-

> Backup-SPFarm -Directory  \*****\backups\ -BackupMethod full
>   -BackupThreads 10 -Force

but my questions are, if our approach is sufficient to covers these scenarios:-

1. let say the database server had a major hardware/OS problem, and we are not able to have it working again. then will the snapshot we have for the database be able to recover us from the database server failure?
2. similar to point one, but let say the application server had a major hardware/OS problem? will the snapshot be sufficient to recover us from the application server failure?
3. since our IT admin are taking snap shots of the servers, then is there any need to do a Backup-SPFarm? as this command will created a huge backup files.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: how many servers in the farm ( sharePoint)?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP we always have one sharepoint application server and one database server. so the answer is one sharepoint server.

Answer (score 3):

I am not big fan of SnapShot as it always cause the problem with us. If i am in your situation, i would do it this way.

- Write it down any web.config changes or special customization to the farm.
- run backup-Spfarm configuration only, to backup the configuration. Daily
- Also backup the service applications and write down the special settings if any.
- backup the SQL databases ( content, config and Services databases). this what you have to plan...i would one full back weekly along with hourly backup.
- also document sql server settings.

Now lets see how it safe us.

1. Let's say, if SQL server goes down...we have SQL backup...build a new sql server and restored the databases...boom its worked....data loss is less than a hour.
2. Lets say SharePoint server went down. Rebuild the server, restore the farm configuration, service application....re attach the databases...boom we are back.
3. If both server go down...apply 1 & 2.

Comment: thanks for the reply. point1) so you do not find any reason to do a full Backup-PSfarm? or this will include all the settings we need? 2) point2, as i know to be able to restore from Backup-SPfarm then we need to build a farm which is identical to the original farm, in other words the new farm need to have the exact cumulative updates, so will restoring the farm configuration be able to build an exact farm as the source? 3) point3, when you say to backup the sql DBs, then you are talking about backuping the sql DBs from the sql management studio, no need to do so from SP?

Comment: 1) restore from the backup-spfarm always pain for us as we have large farms ( 24 servers), even in small farm...you need the same level of CU etc. 2) You have to build the farm with same cu levels, no matter what 3) yes i am atalking about the DB backups from SQL server. it is most reliable thing in industry.

Comment: ok so now you touch my real problem and what our IT admin is saying.. that with server snapshots we do not have to worry about building servers with the same CU level.. and some of our IT admins is saying that snapshots for the vms should be fine!! although MS documentation is saying that it is not supported.. second point, now if i want to take the appraoch of doing a Backup-SPfarm, then after recovering i will need to build a server with the same patches, but not sure if there is any power-shell script which will list what are the patches we have?

Comment: now i know that i can get these patches from "CA >> Upgrade and Migration >>  Manage Patch Status" ,,so i can write them done and update the list after any patching we do to the server.. but how this list will be beneficial for us ? i mean do we have to install all the patches one by one if we need to build a brand new sharepoint server? and what will be the required order? third point, as i know when we do a Backup-spfarm it will contain DB backup files, so we do not have to do the backup from the sql server management studio?

Comment: i remember when i did a backup-spfarm from our SP server, the last back up date on the sql database was updated, so Backup-spfarm can be a replacement for doing sql server backups from the sql server itself?

Comment: Thing, we are telling you best practices/ experience we have...best thing, i would do...test out the scenario and see which one works best for you...if MSFT says its not supported then dont risk your production farm...again decision is yours...

Comment: Its depend on which CU level you are? Cu are cumulative and you need to install the last one which you installed in your current farm....but you should also read the cu documentation if their is any prerequisite....lastly you have to write down what you install...typically build number give u idea.

Comment: @SharePointTestDev yes it can be...if you perform full backup....but question is how often, daily hourly or weekly? You have to plan it...to reduce the data loss...also keep in mind running backup also hit farm performance so should be non business hours.

Comment: now also managing CU is an issue in sharepoint, as for some farms we only install a full CU, run the product configuration wizard, then we got a new farm build number, which is easy to reproduce , as we have to install the same full cu again.. but on some farm , we install full CU yearly , then one each 3-4 months we install sharepoint security updates,, so for these farms how i can document the pathes? so i can build an identical sharepoint server?

Comment: Documentation is key here.....it is recommended  always install CU as it contains security updates for the sharepoint

Comment: i do Backup-spfarm daily after buisness hours, and as part of  our SLA , if any server faced a sever damage , then we guarantee to recover data from previuse date (from the time the Backup-spfarm was done) so there will be a data lost of maximum one day

Comment: ok let say i document what i have inside "CA >> Upgrade and Migration >> Manage Patch Status" .. then how we need to install them? and is there a specific order? or it will be better to rely on what we have inside Control Panel >> installed updates?

Answer (score 2):

There is only one method to ensure that your backup is sufficient: test a restore. I've encountered a surprising number of companies who claim not to have enough resources to be able to test their restores. This is crazy. Test your restores.

Regarding snapshots: "The only supported way of snapshotting a SharePoint farm is to have all SharePoint services stopped first. " [source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2015/08/24/virtual-machine-snapshots-for-sharepoint/)

Also, proper backups could allow point-in-time restores, which nightly snapshots wouldn't.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88091/discussion-on-answer-by-mike2500-backup-our-sharepoint-in-premises-farms-are-we).